# ftp batch directory not found

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am creating a batch file that will FTP a backup of a specific directory from a server that is publicly accessible to a server that is only accessible to those on our network.  (From our webserver to our intranet server).  Since I can't get to the intranet server from the webserver, I've created the FTP batch file on the intranet server.  I have a user set up on my webserver in FileZilla Server that has access to the directory that I want to copy all of the files and subdirectories from.  I have this text file set up (backupTransfer.txt):
    open myIPAddress
    username
    password
    hash
    bin
    lcd E:\backups\website
    mget "C:\Backup\testFile.txt"
    quit

Then I have my batch file to run that (websiteBackup.bat): FTP -v -i -s:C:\batch\backupTransfer.txt

When I run this, I get this message:
ftp>mget "C:\Backup\testFile.txt"
Directory not found
Cannot find list of remote files
ftp> quit

I've tried using cd to specify the directory on the webserver (although, that's not really necessary since the user I'm using only has FTP access to the C:\Backups folder and it's subdirectories.

I don't know if this is relevant information, but I have another batch file that correctly works that transfers a file from the intranet server to the webserver.  I just can't seem to get the intranet to pull a file from the webserver.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The root folder of your ftp is / not c:\batch

Comment: I know, c:\batch is on the intranet server is where I have the .txt file saved and where I'm running the batch file from.  But I change the local directory to E:\backups\website so that when get I get the files from the other server (C:\Backup) they go there.

Comment: ok sorry was out of subject, do you have more info if you remove -v from ftp command ? mget "C:\Backup\testFile.txt" will try to access c:\backup on the ftpserver, i dont think this is valid (maybe /backup/testfile.txt will work ? )

Comment: If I remove -v from the ftp command, I get the same results (with an extra line thrown in that says "200 Type set to I).
And if I change to "mget /backup/testfile.txt" (without the quotes), I get the same results.